# Get value from the form by javascript flashes

Tags: javascript, forms

```
    <body>
        search:<input type="text" name="name" id="uniqueID" value="value" />
        <button onclick="myFunction()">submit</button>
        <p id="surprise"></p>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
             x = document.getElementById("uniqueID").value;
            console.log(x);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

If I put the input field and button inside a `<form>` the value appear for second and disappear why is that? ("flashes")

Comment: is this inside a form?

Comment: Please elaborate what error you are getting and what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

By default **`<button>`** in a form acts as **`<input type="submit">`**
so whenever you click on the button, the data is posted and the page is reloaded.
The reloading makes the value disappear.

Try this :

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST/GET" action="#" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
.
.
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function myFunction(){
    x = document.getElementById("uniqueID").value;
    console.log(x);
    return false;
}
```